# Python: Dictionary-like object in dataframe to new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Hello I've done some webscraping and I have a dictionary-like object that is in one of the columns of my dataframe.

`data.offerAggregate.property_aggregate.property.floors` is the column name and the rest is a value inside the column.

```
data.offerAggregate.property_aggregate.property.floors
0  [{'units': [{'features': [{'Code': 'chairs', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'window', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'balcony', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'fridge', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'stove', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'oven', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'microwave', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'washing-machine', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'dryer', 'Exists': False}, {'Code': 'dishwasher', 'Exists': False}, {'Code': 'table', 'Exists': True}]}, {'features': [{'Code': 'toilet', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'sink', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'bathtub', 'Exists': False}, {'Code': 'shower', 'Exists': True}]}, {'features': [{'Code': 'wardrobe', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'chest-of-drawers', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'desk', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'chairs', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'sofa', 'Exists': False}, {'Code': 'sofa-bed', 'Exists': False}, {'Code': 'window', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'balcony', 'Exists': False}, {'Code': 'tv', 'Exists': False}]}, {'features': [{'Code': 'desk', 'Exists': False}, {'Code': 'chairs', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'sofa', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'sofa-bed', 'Exists': False}, {'Code': 'coffee-table', 'Exists': False}, {'Code': 'table', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'tv', 'Exists': False}]}, {'features': [{'Code': 'chest-of-drawers', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'desk', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'chairs', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'sofa', 'Exists': False}, {'Code': 'sofa-bed', 'Exists': False}, {'Code': 'window', 'Exists': True}, {'Code': 'balcony', 'Exists': False}]}]}]
```

What I would like to end up with is a new dataframe that has the Code values as the column names and the Exists values as the column value.
So instead of `{'Code': 'chairs', 'Exists': True}`, I would have `chairs` `True`

I tried making it into a json object so I can access the keys and store them into a new dataframe, but I'm getting errors.

```
df_floors = pd.DataFrame(df['data.offerAggregate.property_aggregate.property.floors'])

jsonObj = df_floors.to_json(orient='records')

print(jsonObj['Code'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I'm not sure if this is the right approach but any ideas or help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please format your code so it's easier to read. As it is now it's difficult to understand

Comment: Check the format of the jsonObj so you can see if its what your expecting. print(jsonObj)

Answer (score 0):

Check the format of the jsonObj so you can see if its what your expecting.

```
print(jsonObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.DataFrame(row[0]['units'][0]['features'])
```

produces:

```
               Code  Exists
0            chairs    True
1            window    True
2           balcony    True
3            fridge    True
4             stove    True
5              oven    True
6         microwave    True
7   washing-machine    True
8             dryer   False
9        dishwasher   False
10            table    True
```

or

---

```
print(pd.DataFrame([{x['Code']: x['Exists'] for x in row[0]['units'][0]['features']}]))
```

produces:

```
   balcony  chairs  dishwasher  dryer  fridge  microwave  oven  stove  table  
0     True    True       False  False    True       True  True   True   True
```

Comment: What does w[0] represent here because when i change it to df_floors[0], it doesn't work.